MSP: Looking for a clever way to simulate the functionality of a "Application.ProjectAfterClose" event
I have a combobox that I would like to keep a list of all open projects.
Meaning that it would need to be updated when a project opens or closes. I have already implemented the ProjectOpen event, but am having trouble with finding a solution for when a project closes.
Just using the ProjectBeforeCloseEvent will not be enough, because it triggers before the save project popup occurs, and the user might cancel.
At the moment, I am using a combination of the ProjectBeforeCloseEvent and the WindowActivateEvent as a workaround.
However, there is no way to detect whether or not the user cancels the closing of the last open project (Since WindowActivateEvent is never triggered).
I would prefer to not have to use a timer that checks if the project closed or not after a period of time.
Edit: I made some changes to my code, as there was a way for the user to remove a prj name in the combobox without closing the prj. However, I still have not found a way to fix my main issue (When the last open project is closed).
Here is my updated code in case anyone would like to see,
private void _prjApp_WindowActivateEvent(MSP.Window activatedWindow)
{
    List<string> prjFileNames = ReturnOpenProjFileNames();

    if (projectOpened)
    {
        foreach (var prjName in prjFileNames)
        {
            if (cbMSP.Items.Contains(prjName) == false)
            {
                AddMSPToComboBox(prjName);
            }
        }
    }

    if (projectClosed)
    {
        for (int i = cbMSP.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            string prjName = cbMSP.Items[i].ToString();

            if (prjFileNames.Contains(prjName) == false)
            {
                DeleteMSPInComboBox(prjName);
            }
        }
    }

    projectClosed = false;
    projectOpened = false;
}

I have two boolean variables that are assigned to their corresponding events (ProjectBeforeCloseEvent and NewProjectEvent). This is to hopefully reduce unnecessary code running when a user just changes the active project.

If the user cancels the close, you don’t need to recompute the list of projects, right? So if they don’t cancel and the project is closed, does the activate event not fire?

@RachelHettinger Yes, if the user cancels the close, I won't need to recompute the list of projects. However, if they do decide to close the last opened project, neither the activate nor the deactivate event is triggered.

I also just noticed another issue with my current implementation. The user could cancel the closing action of a project and then when they change the active project, it will remove the project from the combobox that I stored in my tuple.
